# Tensorflow 1.13.1 tf.data map multiple images with a single row together

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I'm building my tf dataset where there are multiple inputs (images and numerical/categorical data). The problem I am having is that multiple images correspond to the same row in the pd.Dataframe I have. *I am doing regression.*

So how, (even when shuffling all the inputs) do I ensure that each image gets mapped to the correct row?

Again, say I have 10 rows, and 100 images, with 10 images corresponding to a particular row. Now we shuffle the dataset, and we want to make sure that the shuffled images all correspond to their respective row.

I am using `tf.data.Dataset` to do this. **I also have a directory structure such that the folder name corresponds to an element in the DataFrame, which is what I was thinking of using if I knew how to do the mapping**

i.e. `folder1` would be in the df with cols like `dir_name, feature1, feature2, ...`. **Naturally, the `dir_names` should not be passed as data into the model to fit on.**

```
#images
path_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(paths)
image_ds = path_ds.map(load_and_preprocess_image, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)

#numerical&categorical features. First remove the dirs
x_train_input = X_train[X_train.columns.difference(['dir_name'])]
x_train_input=np.expand_dims(x_train_input, axis=1)
text_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x_train_input)

#labels, y_train's cols are: 'label' and 'dir_name'
label_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    tf.cast(y_train['label'], tf.float32))

# test creation of dataset without prior shuffling.
xtrain_ = tf.data.Dataset.zip((image_ds, text_ds))
model_ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip((xtrain_, label_ds))


# Shuffling
BATCH_SIZE = 64

# Setting a shuffle buffer size as large as the dataset ensures that
# data is completely shuffled
ds = model_ds.shuffle(buffer_size=len(paths))
ds = ds.repeat()
ds = ds.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
# prefetch lets the dataset fetch batches in the background while the
# model is training
# ds = ds.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
ds = ds.prefetch(buffer_size=BATCH_SIZE)
```

Comment: I'm thinking a generator might may help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution would be to utilize TFRecords for storing the data and holding it's integrity. This will also open doors for other efficiencies as well.

What the below code is doing...

- Create dummy data. All need to be arrays with the same datatype found in the _parse_function. You can change that dtype, just also ensure you change it for your data too.
- Create a dictionary that holds the arrays by name
- Create `feature_dimensions` object that holds the shape of all arrays
- Create TFRecords by looping over data dict. You can create one large file, or many small ones. This is a good starting point for you however.
- Declare functions for generating the dataset. You can add and modify whatever logic you want there. The key, however, is that these functions use the `feature_dimensions` object to remember how to put the data back together
- Create a dataset
- Generate a sample. The result is a dictionary with a batch-size worth of data.

You should be able to just run this sample code all by itself and have no issues. Then just make the changes you need for it to work in your problem.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from functools import partial

# Create dummy data, TODO replace with your own logic
# 10 images per row in DF
images_per_example = 10
examples = 200

# Save name for TFRecords, you can create multiple and pass a list of the names as well
save_name = "my_tfrecords.tfrecords"

# DF, dataframe with random categorical data
x_data = pd.DataFrame(data=(np.random.normal(size=(examples, 50)) > 0).astype(np.float32))
y_data = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=(examples, )).reshape(-1, 1).astype(np.float32)


def load_and_preprocess_image(file):
    # For dummy purposes generating instead of loading
    img = np.random.uniform(high=255, low=0, size=(15, 15))
    return (img / 255.).astype(np.float32)


# I would preprocess your images prior to creating the tfrecords file
img_data = np.array([[load_and_preprocess_image("add_logic") for j in range(images_per_example)]
                     for k in range(examples)])

# Prepare for tfrecords
data_dict = dict()
data_dict["images"] = img_data  # Already an array
data_dict["x_data"] = x_data.values  # Ensure it's an array
data_dict["y_data"] = y_data  # Already an array

# Remember the dimensions for later restoration, replacing number of examples with -1
feature_dimensions = {k: v.shape for k, v in data_dict.items()}
feature_dimensions = {k: tuple([-1] + list(v[1:])) for k, v in feature_dimensions.items()}


def _bytes_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))


writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(save_name)

# Create TFRecords file
for i in range(examples):

    example_dict = dict()  # New dictionary for each single example
    for name, data in data_dict.items():
        # if name == "images":
        #     break
        example_dict[name] = data[i]

    # Define the features of your tfrecord
    feature = {k: _bytes_feature(tf.compat.as_bytes(v.tostring())) for k, v in example_dict.items()}

    # Serialize to string and write to file
    example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature))
    writer.write(example.SerializeToString())

writer.close()


# Declare functions for creating dataset
def _parse_function(proto, feature_dimensions_: dict):
    # define your tfrecord again. Remember that you saved your image as a string.
    keys_to_features = {k: tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string) for k in feature_dimensions_.keys()}

    # Load one example
    parsed_features = tf.parse_single_example(proto, keys_to_features)

    # Split data
    for k, v in parsed_features.items():
        parsed_features[k] = tf.decode_raw(v, tf.float32)

    return parsed_features


def create_tf_dataset(file_paths: str, feature_dimensions_: dict, batch_size=64):
    # This works with arrays as well
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(file_paths)

    # Maps the parser on every filepath in the array. You can set the number of parallel loaders here
    parse_function = partial(_parse_function, feature_dimensions_=feature_dimensions_)
    dataset = dataset.map(parse_function, num_parallel_calls=1)

    # This dataset will go on forever
    dataset = dataset.repeat()

    # Set the number of datapoints you want to load and shuffle
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(batch_size)  # Put whatever you want here

    # Set the batchsize
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)

    # Set up a pipeline
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(batch_size)  # Put whatever you want here

    # Create an iterator
    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()

    # Create your tf representation of the iterator
    parsed_features = iterator.get_next()

    # Reshape arrays and cast to float
    for k, v in parsed_features.items():
        parsed_features[k] = tf.reshape(v, feature_dimensions_[k])
    for k, v in parsed_features.items():
        parsed_features[k] = tf.cast(v, tf.float32)

    return parsed_features


# Create dataset
ds = create_tf_dataset(save_name, feature_dimensions, batch_size=64)

# The final result is a dictionary with the names used above
sample = tf.Session().run(ds)

print("Sample Length:", len(sample))
print("Sample Keys:", sample.keys())
print("images shape:", sample["images"].shape)
print("x_data shape:", sample["x_data"].shape)
print("y_data shape:", sample["y_data"].shape)
```

*Printed Results*

> ```
> Sample Length: 3
> Sample Keys: dict_keys(['images', 'x_data', 'y_data'])
> images shape: (64, 10, 15, 15)
> x_data shape: (64, 50)
> y_data shape: (64, 1)
> ```

Comment: Thank you! I slightly modified the example to also take numerical as well as categorical input and it worked perfectly!